# how to autogenerate code in java?

Tags: java, javafx

I am making a GUI where a person clicks on a checkbox and a code for whatever he checked on is generated and appended to the java file. 
For example, a check box saying "Output to the console function" will generate...(I can handle the GUI, don't worry about that ^_^)

```
public static void log(String text){
 System.out.println(text);
}
```

I can hard code that but I know how to hard code that in a form of a string and I can then print that to the console. I don't know how to append it to the file itself. I can append it to a text file if thats useful.

I love the auto-generated try-catch block. It is sort what I am expecting. You click on surround with try-catch block. Currently, my code can just output whatever I want in a form of a string.

**EDIT:**

To make it simpler, new scenario :I already have pre-defined functions

names of functions a ,b ,c,d

so there will be 4 checkbox, and all the functions that i checked will be in a new function which i can name via a text box

for example, 
If I only checked a AND b

```
public static void e (){
a();
b();
}
```

Comment: You need to find all the properties of Checkbox as well as find how checkbox is declared and in how many various ways. Use the generic one which would apply for all. Also try to check netbeans and other IDE which provide drag and drop facility.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question

Comment: you want to make popup menu over which, if you click on that suggestion the code will be replaced with the previous that's the only thing you want??

Comment: Are you saying you want to update the Java file in Eclipse directly with your GUI? is the GUI standalone, or an Eclipse plugin? What is your question really: 1-How to append text to a file? 2-How to generate code? 3-Something else entirely

Comment: I just want a GUI which can combine 2 or more functions for me into one function. Where each function is displayed on the GUI as a checkbox. The new function should append to the same or another JAva file

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps!

To append a file,
Use:

```
 File java_file= new File("java_file.class")
 PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(java_file, true));
```

Then use an item listener for the checkboxes:

```
addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                System.out.println(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED
                    ? "SELECTED" : "DESELECTED");
            }
        });
```

Comment: I don't think this is exactly what I asked for! But thanks for trying! :D